# How do I change the IconComponent of a NativeSelect depending if it is opened or not

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am customizing NativeSelect (in Material UI v3). I want to change the IconElement depending on whether the NativeSelect is open / expanded or not. With `NativeSelect` it seems I cannot use the `open`, `onOpen` or `onClose` props.

```
<NativeSelect
            input={<InputBase
                className={dropdownSelectStyle.rootInputBaseStyle}/>}
            IconComponent={ExpandMore}
            {...props}>
            {
                dropdownElements.map((currEntry: string): HTMLOptionElement => (
                    <option key={currEntry} value={currEntry}>
                        {currEntry}
                    </option>
                ))
            }

        </NativeSelect>
```

I would like the `IconComponent` here to be the `ExpandLess` icon when the `NativeSelect` is open and change back to `ExpandMore` when the `NativeSelect` is closed.

Answer (score 1):

The [NativeSelect](https://material-ui.com/api/native-select/) doesn't allow for a click handler for when it opens (as you already mentioned). However, it does allow for some css modifications on open.

> iconOpen  .MuiNativeSelect-iconOpen   Styles applied to the icon component if the popup is open.

Since the icon you're wanting to apply when it's open is simply an upside down version of the icon when it's closed, then just apply `transform: rotate(180deg)` to the icon when it's opened. This way, you can also add a transform timer on it for a smoother effect.

Comment: Tried it in Material UI v4 and still no joy. See my answer with my updated code above.

Answer (score 0):

Still having issues despite using the suggestion above. My code

Styling:

```
const useStyles: JSON = makeStyles({
    root: {
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 0,
        borderColor: "#bfbfbf",
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        boxShadow: "0 1px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16)",
        minWidth: 279,
        "&$iconOpen": {
            transform: "rotate(180deg)"
        },
    },
    focused: {},
    iconOpen: {}
});
```

Main Code :

```
function MyDropdownSelect(props: MyDropdownSelectPropsType): NativeSelect {
    const dropdownSelectStyle: JSON = useStyles();
    return (
        <NativeSelect
            className={dropdownSelectStyle.root}
            input={<InputBase/>}
            IconComponent={ExpandMore}
            {...props}
        >
            {
                dropdownElements.map((currEntry: string): HTMLOptionElement => (
                    <option key={currEntry} value={currEntry}>
                        {currEntry}
                    </option>
                ))
            }

        </NativeSelect>
    );
}
```

Shouldn't this work ??

**Codesandbox added** (05/11/2019) -https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-kowalevski-rol3v?fontsize=14

Comment: Sure. Codesandbox here - https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-kowalevski-rol3v?fontsize=14

Comment: I would suggest opening an issue on github for this. Their logic for applying classes is broken. Even their documented global class of ".MuiNativeSelect-iconOpen" isn't being applied when the menu is opened. Because of that, any additional modifications that are supposed to run at the same time are also not running. The only other solution I can think of (while using the native select) is to add a div container to the select and change the icon based off of a state change. However, it's pretty janky in practice since there's no event listener for when the select box is closed in the browser.

Comment: Here's my example of what I was talking about: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-albattani-39srm